# How to send AWS Kinesis Video Stream (frames) to EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

**Requirement:** For deep learning predictions, I want to send the frame from my local system camera to EC2 instance for predictions.

Work done till now:

1. I am able test my deep learning code on my local system.
2. I have uploaded the code on EC2 instance.
3. I am able to send the live feed from my local camera to AWS Kinesis Video Stream.

**Problem:** I don't know how to send the AWS Kinesis video stream frames to EC2 instance for predictions. I searched everywhere, I know this is one of the use case of AWS Kinesis Video to send the frame to EC2 but I don't know how it will be possible.

Comment: Thank You Everyone. Parser library and GetMedia API didn't work. So, written my own python code to get the video on the instance

Comment: HI, Ankit, does your python code is opensource, please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the code in the EC2 to consume the frames being sent by your system camera. You can base your application off the parser library (https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library) and run it on the EC2 instance to capture the frames and perform deep learning predictions. Hope this gives an idea!

Comment: Yes, I have heard about streams-parser-library. Please if possible, can you just add a snippet how can I integrate my application with the library which you have mentioned. Means how to use it. I read the documentation but no idea where to add the code with my prediction code. (I am new to it and no idea with it). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Per @divku suggestion, you can use GetMedia API and the parser library she referenced to read and parse out and "consume" the frames. You can cut GitHub issues against the assets in question to get more precise and timely responces.

Comment: Can you tell, where should I write the GetMedia API? I am new to it. Thanks in advance